# Internal CPS Error: The Solution Build Manager was expected to have called BeginBuild by now

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing a program using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (VC++). Several days ago, I built a project and the program ran successfully. Today I added some new codes into the program, but an error occurred when I rebuilt the project.

The error is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ProcessImage, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Error: Internal CPS Error: The Solution Build Manager was expected to have called BeginBuild by now.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The new codes that I added today are just several simple statements, I can confirm that they are correct.

So, can anybody tell me what's wrong and how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, if everything is correct in the new code, then there should be no errors. Otherwise it is not correct and you should include your code into the question.

Comment: Thank you. I reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and ran the project sucessfully without changing anything. Maybe it's something wrong with the previous Visual Stduio 2010 installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but since I run into the problem right now and all the solutions available in the web recomment a repair of VS 2010 installation which might be time consuming escpecially if a series of fixes are applied in VS (so they must be reapplied) I'll post an alternative answer.

Using Sysinternals process monitor during VS load I discovered multiple Access Denied error messages on various VS related registry keys.

After correcting these registry key permissions for the current OS user, VS build completed succesfully.